# JQuery delete empty divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

`<div class="container-mob"></div>`

I have multiple `divs` like this, some of them are empty (have no children) and all of them have the same class name. I want to remove the empty divs. I've tried:

```
if ($('.container-mob').is(':empty')) { 
          $('.container-mob').remove();
        }
```

Is there any way to do this with jQuery or JavaScript?

[Screenshot divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PrFK.png)

Comment: Can't you specify the classes by giving them an unique id?

Comment: Correct would be just:  `$('.container-mob').is(':empty').remove();` without the if

Comment: there is a 240 divs i cant do them one by one

Comment: @johnSmith it's not deleting although

Comment: @johnSmith `.is()` returns a boolean

Comment: @freedomn-m you are right we can use `$('.container-mob:empty').remove()`

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi yes, I was going to suggest that but your answer popped up as I was typing :)

Comment: @freedomn-m it's returning false

Comment: @M.Mevlevi ignore the `.is(":empty")` suggestion - you *can* use that inside your loop, but not in the way suggested - the provided answer should get you what you want (and if it doesn't the `.is(":empty")` won't either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one: `$('.container-mob:empty').remove()`

```js
console.log('all empty container',$('.container-mob:empty').length);

$('.container-mob:empty').remove();

console.log('after remove all empty container',$('.container-mob:empty').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="container-mob"></div>
    <div class="container-mob"></div>
    <div class="container-mob"></div>
    <div class="container-mob"></div>
    <div class="container-mob">not empty</div>
```

Comment: @M.Mevlevi why? what is the problem? Do you get aby error?

Comment: all empty container 0
after remove all empty container 0

Comment: @M.Mevlevi In my snippet `all empty container 4` and after is `0`.   you saw the result in my snippet or in your code?

Comment: @M.Mevlevi Are you sure the `.container-mob` is really empty? you can check that via `Developer Tools`

Comment: @M.Mevlevi As you can see my snippet worked correctly. So you need to make sure the `div` is really empty. maybe some operation add children or text to your `div`.

Comment: @M.Mevlevi which browser do you use?

Comment: I've added an ss you can take a look

Comment: chrome browser abcd

Comment: @M.Mevlevi Are you sure the remove script run after div loaded?

Comment: @M.Mevlevi How do you add those div? statically? or with loop? or...?

Comment: yes I'm sure if you want I could add you to my Github project

Comment: @M.Mevlevi if this isn't working for you, you'll need to provide more information.  Ideally in a **snippet** *in the question* that **demonstrates the issue**.   Given the information provided in the question, this answer provides an valid answer, with a demonstrated snippet showing it working.  If it's not working for you, then there must be some other information not provided.

Comment: @M.Mevlevi Create working code as a snippet here or on stackblitz. without code anyone can't help you

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi I'm working on Django divs are created in Django for loop

Comment: @M.Mevlevi I think the problem is that the remove script run before rendering of element. try this one and let me know what happened.  `window.setTimeout(() => { $('.container-mob:empty').remove(); },3000);`

Comment: [link](https://github.com/Mehmet-pro/covid19) I made the project public if you want you can take a look

Comment: @M.Mevlevi The easiest way is that try to remove the div via click event. put a button and after the all div are rendered then click on button to remove. You know I still suspect a delay problem. let me know after testing

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi  I Solved it By giving every div a specific id, but there is only one bug that is #Iran (Islamic Republic of) in cases like this it's giving an error because the id has parentheses do you have any idea about how to ignore it?

Comment: @M.Mevlevi you can use `replace` method to remove all of `()`: like this: `"(Islamic Republic of)".replace(/\(|\)/g, '');`

Comment: @M.Mevlevi But I think space also is not valid for `id`

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Sure Thank you for help could you vote up for me pls?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get all empty div's like and call `remove()` function on empty div's array

HTML:

```
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block">Data</div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block">Data</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".block:empty").remove()
```